# Java market lab gui

Tags: java

I've been working on this java program for a while but i've run into a wall and I need help. I run this program and everything works as it should, except the coupon button. Well it works but when I use a coupon number that is greater than the total price it shows a negative number. I need help making it so that a zero appears when A higher coupon number is entered. I think I have to write a loop like ( if bill < 0) { str = "0"}. the code is linked below.

http://codepad.org/EhLICVGT

Comment: Please provide how to test the code.

Comment: JCreator. All you need is the file in the link and a text document called "final.txt" with this information in it - http://textuploader.com/oidq 
(If you guys don't mind I can post the zip file somewhere

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code, not just a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have logical error in bill var; As I can get it, the coupon shoud have **many items** but there is only one bill per coupon right? so please dont do bill var as local field cause its re-inits the **bill** each time event occur; So to make it iterate data make class field see example :

**problem code**

```
...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    String str;
    String couponReciept;
    String coupontest;
    int couponnumber;
    int marketnumber;
    double price;
    double bill = 0; //<---logical error "local field"
    DecimalFormat output = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    index = grocery.getSelectedIndex();


    price = groceryprice[index];

    System.out.print("Cost = " + price + "$ ");

    str = quanityText.getText();
    marketnumber = Integer.parseInt(str);
    bill = marketnumber * price;


    if (couponyes.isSelected())
   {

    coupontest = couponText.getText();
    couponnumber = Integer.parseInt(coupontest);

    bill = bill - couponnumber;

   }
  ...
```

**fixed code**

```
...
double bill = 0;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    String str;
    String couponReciept;
    String coupontest;
    int couponnumber;
    int marketnumber;
    double price;

    DecimalFormat output = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    index = grocery.getSelectedIndex();


    price = groceryprice[index];

    System.out.print("Cost = " + price + "$ ");

    str = quanityText.getText();
    marketnumber = Integer.parseInt(str);
    bill = marketnumber * price;


    if (couponyes.isSelected())
   {

    coupontest = couponText.getText();
    couponnumber = Integer.parseInt(coupontest);

    bill = bill - couponnumber;

   }
  ...
```

I am not sure will it fix the whole code; But in some terms it is the way to fix more or less your specific question issue

Good luck